# Get the ID from the newly created row rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How might you get the id of a newly created row in rails?

For example,

```
Session.create(:user_id => user_id, :email => email )
```

Answer (score 1):

I wished there were more documentations for rails... oh well, for the future

```
session = Session.create(:user_id => user_id, :email => email )
puts session.id
```

Comment: In case some new Rails users don't get wrong impression of Rails... In comparison to other web frameworks out there, Rails is one of few web frameworks that's well documented. Have you tried working with some Perl web frameworks? Rails docs are certainly not perfect. There are so many classes and so many methods within those classes that it would literally take millions of man hours to document everything. However, the fact that when you `create` an object from a model automatically is created with `id` is so widely known, that I didn't even think that anyone would ask that question.